# How to get specific attribute value from a DIV by class and by another attribute value (PHP)

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domxpath

I'm trying to get the values of all data-user attributes from DIVs where class = "card-insert" and data-name = "USER_1" from this URL:

https://schah.live/data.html

So in the end, I would have an array or five variables that contain data-user content.

eg:
21501,
21502,
21503,
21504,
21505,

I tried the following code, but it's not working:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://schah.live/data.html');
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($homepage);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {

$mydata = "//div[@data-name='USER_1']";
$entries = $xpath->query($img)->item($i);
$mydata = $entries->getAttribute("data-user");

echo $mydata. "<br>";
    
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);

$result = [];

foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="card-insert"][@data-name="USER_1"]/@data-user') as $item)
{
    $result[$item->value] = $item->value;
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks mate!
One more thing, how can I set wildcard for data-name="USER_1" like data-name="*_1" -- as if data-name attribs that contain "_1"

Comment: @Schahryar, you need "contains", "starts-with" and "ends-with": [sample one](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html), [sample two](https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html)